# Get number of column in a CollectionView IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

I use an `UICollectionView` in my first app. My problem is I can't get the number of column (or line) calculated in the `UICollectionView`.

The `UICollectionView` is inside an `UIScrollView`, and I want to set the height of the `UICollectionView` because I don't want to scroll in the `UICollectionView` but I want to see all the items.

Is this possible?

Thanks,
F.G

Comment: Do you mean number of columns ? Or number (index) of column clicked etc.?

Comment: after rendering, the number of items for example in the first line, the 2nd, etc... and the number of line in the collectionView

Comment: You can get that by dividing the width of the collection view with the width of the collectionViewCell.

Comment: yes it's possible but is there another way for knowing  this?

Comment: I don't think that there's any method for this, because the collectionView's layout is dynamic, and is depending on the width and height..

Comment: Ok thank you for this information. other thing: is it possible to disable scroll in the CollectionView and to se entirely the items?

Comment: Try this: self.collectionView.scrollEnabled = NO;

Comment: scroll is disabled but I see only the first line :(

Comment: Try setting the content size.

Comment: this is exactly what I need to do, but I can't calculate the height

Comment: Can you use .sizeToFit() on the scroll view? So it resizes to enclose the subviews? (Your CollectionView in this case)

Comment: Unfortunatly, ,siezToFit() does nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many researches I found the solution:

- I don't need to know the number of column or line in the collection view if I want to fix the height.
- The height of the collection view can be updated automatically:

**Add a height constrain to the collection view**

Add the CollectionView and the constrain as outlets in the ViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstrainCollectionView: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
```

After the view Load, update the height of the CollectionView:

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    heightConstrainCollectionView.constant = myCollectionView.contentSize.height
    }
```

If the user rotate the device, update the CollectionView's height:

```
override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    heightConstrainCollectionView.constant = myCollectionView.contentSize.height

// Add this if you want to see the height after rotation
    println("New Width: \(newspaperCollectionView.contentSize.height)")
}
```

Now I can't scroll in my CollectionView and the CollectionView show all the items

Comment: Wouldn't it be more correct to change constraint only inside `override func viewWillLayoutSubviews()`?